How to stop the jdbc PostgreSQL port being dynamically set every test run?
Working with a Java/Spring Boot/Kubernetes/JOOQ/Postgres stack.
The Postgres standard port for runtime 5432.
When running unit tests the port is selected dynamically every time and is shown in the logs, e.g. from console log:

Container is started (JDBC URL:
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:60821/test?loggerLevel=OFF)

where 60821 will change on every run.
This makes connecting to the database to debug a pain as the pgAdmin connection needs to be reset each time the tests are rerun.
Is there a way to fix the test port temporarily for local debugging, e.g., set something in application-test.yaml?

For tests it is usually desirable to use a random port so they don't conflict if you have multiple tests running on the machine concurrently (e.g. on a build server). And whether or not you can set a fixed port depends on what you're using to launch that test instance.

That's fine, good clarification re the build serve, I updated the post. I want to fix the port temporarily to help with local testing.

For unit tests, can you mock your database layer (write your own implementation of the JPA interfaces) so that you don't need complicated infrastructure to run tests?  And then you can run larger integration tests against a real database that you control.

You need to provide more info: what is launching that PostgreSQL instance, how have you configured that?
